# facebook graph api - get posted images from users on page

Tags: facebook, graph, sdk

I've searched a lot, but I did not get any full information.

I need to get all images which are posted to a specific fb page by users. And do I really ned to get that app reviewed? I only need this application during an exhibition over a weekend.

The fans take a picture at our booth and post it on our timeline. These images are to be displayed automatically on a screen.

How do I get to the pictures via the Facebook API?

**update:**

My first move was with the following:

`graph.facebook.com/v3.1/[pageid]/feed?fields=picture,message,from`

Since I need only the posts from others, I'm going to filter the response object.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: did you already check out the api docs? that´s where you need to go first. right now this is way too broad for stackoverflow, i´m afraid. you need to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: okay you're right! I was a little short. I've updated my post with my current solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so `PAGE-ID/visitor_posts?fields=picture,message` did the trick!